# pkg set-publisher fails on Solaris 11

Tags: package-management, solaris, drm

I'm trying to install Sun/Oracle Studio on Solaris 11. We have a free developer account on the Sun Developer Network. I have the developer key and certificate. I scp'd them to the UltraSPARC workstation. I then ssh'd into the workstation (the workstation is headless).

According to [How to Install a Certificate and Key for the Oracle Solaris Support Repository](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54747/installkeycert.html) (this is step 2):

```
$ sudo pkg set-publisher -G '*' -M '*' \
  -g https://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/support/ \
  -c ~/pkg.oracle.com.certificate.pem \
  -k ~/pkg.oracle.com.key.pem  solaris
pkg set-publisher: Could not refresh the catalog for solaris

https protocol error: code: 401 reason: Unauthorized
URL: 'https://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/support/solaris/catalog/1/catalog.attrs'
```

And:

```
$ ls ~/pkg.*
/export/home/jwalton/pkg.oracle.com.certificate.pem
/export/home/jwalton/pkg.oracle.com.key.pem
```

Sun has a troubleshooting page at [Cannot Access Publisher or Repository](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54739/uriaccess.html), but when I search for *"pkg set-publisher: Could not refresh the catalog for solaris"* there are no hits. (I must be the only guy on the planet getting that error).

I seem to be missing something or the docs are not quite correct.

How do I install the certificate and key so I can download Sun Studio?

Comment: Might be the only guy using this & Solaris for that matter....8-o

Comment: @slm - Lol... Solaris is an acquired taste.  I contribute to a few free projects and I bought the workstation for testing. Otherwise I would probably avoid Solaris. The one that befuddles me is the OOM kills. I have 8 GB of RAM and the damn machine runs out of memory with no load.

Comment: I used it for the first 15+ yrs of my career so I'm familiar w/ it. It did it's job.

Comment: What if you `truss` it?

Comment: Also try some `-vv` on it - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36802/tspkginstall.html

Comment: It's probably this - https://community.oracle.com/thread/2543121.

Comment: Thanks for your help @slm. We figured out it was the wrong repository.

Answer (score 1):

This command from [How to Install a Certificate and Key for the Oracle Solaris Support Repository](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54747/installkeycert.html) was incorrect:

```
$ sudo pkg set-publisher -G '*' -M '*' \
  -g https://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/support/ \
  -c ~/pkg.oracle.com.certificate.pem \
  -k ~/pkg.oracle.com.key.pem  solaris
```

Here is the correct command:

```
$ sudo pkg set-publisher \
  -G "*" -g https://pkg.oracle.com/solarisstudio/release \
  -k ~/pkg.oracle.com.key.pem \
  -c ~/pkg.oracle.com.certificate.pem solarisstudio
```

Comment: Bad docs, ugh, glad you figured it out.

Comment: The command was correct for the Oracle Solaris OS support repository - you're using it with the Studio compilers release repository instead, so would need a different command.